# Android: Set number of visible items in a list view

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

Is there a way to set the number of visible items in a list view? Say, I have 10 list items and I only want to show 5 items at a time/per page. And that each item view automatically adjusts its height relative to the screen.

Comment: the amount of Items shown in the Listview depends on the size that is available for the list

Comment: hi thanks for the link. i think i got my answer. cheers!